# If a regex match is found assign it to a variable

Tags: c#, beginner, regex

I am searching a string for a pattern that matches `Material=`. Some examples are `Material=ABC123,Color=444555`, `Material=332212,Color=192929`
I am new to C# and I learned about capture groups but I am wondering if its possible to do it in a cleaner way?

```
var pattern = new Regex("(?<label>Material)=(?<value>[^,]+)");
Match match = pattern.Match(Row2.Attributes);
var materialCode = (match.Success) ? match.Groups["value"].Value : "NA";
```

Edit:

I store `materialCode` into a database so it can't be null. If a value isn't found it has to be "NA". Also there are lots of combos which is why I specify I need whatever value after the `=` but before the `,` in the regex

Comment: That looks like the right way to me.

Answer (score 3):

Do not set the `materialCode` to another string. I am not sure, but `NA` might also be a valid choice for `Material=<value>`. Instead, just set it to `null`.

As for the pattern itself, instead of searching for `[^,]` (anything except `,`), you should look for only the valid values. Based on the given examples, I'd assume that only alphanumericals are accepted. If there is a limit on the length, then you should specify that as well.

Since, you are only looking for values assigned to `Material` property; no need to store the word `Material` as a matched-group result.

For eg.

```
Material=(?<value>[A-Z\d]{6})
```

Comment: I store `materialCode` into a database so it can't be null. If a value isn't found it has to be "NA". Also there are lots of combos which is why I specify I need whatever value after the `=` but before the `,`

Comment: @Anonguy123 Those specifications/limitations should be mentioned in question.